# SQL / Hibernate Criteria - Group By Trouble

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some trouble here to create an appropriate SQL query. Any help will be much appreciated!

Some background:

I have the following entities

```
Equipment
id
nickname
owner_indicator
{...}

EquipmentGroup_Equipment
equipment_id
equipment_group_id

EquipmentGroup
id
name
description
```

I need to do a SQL / JPA Hibernate query that returns me:

```
EquipmentGroup.name, EquipmentGroup.description, Equipment.owner_indicator
```

And this will be grouped by EquipmentGroup.id, so if I have 10 equipments inside the group it will return information grouped by the EquipmentGroup.

The thing is, when I have for example more than one `owner_indicator` inside a EquipmentGroup it will return 2 rows. This is SQL 101. But i **must** return only one line with a blank text instead of the Owner Indicator.

What is the easiest way to do this ? I'd be glad to have the answer in SQL, but much more than glad to have it in Criteria JPA, heh.

If it does matter, I'm using Oracle 12c.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

As requested, here is some data:

```
Equipment
id    nickname   owner_indicator
1     EQP01      'V'
2     EQP02      'T'

EquipmentGroup_Equipment
equipment_group_id equipment_id
1                  1
1                  2

EquipmentGroup
id    name    description
1     GRP1    Group 1
```

My wanted resultSet is:

```
Result
EquipmentGroup.name EquipmentGroup.description, Equipment.owner_indicator
GRP1                Group 1                     (empty string)
```

That empty string would be returned because I don't want 2 rows, like

```
Result
EquipmentGroup.name EquipmentGroup.description, Equipment.owner_indicator
GRP1                Group 1                     'T'
GRP1                Group 1                     'V'
```

If anything more than that is needed please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You can also include the SQL statement that you have already tried.

Comment: You know that the language used by Hibernate queries is not SQL, but HQL, right?

Comment: @JBNizet yep but if someone helps me with SQL I can manage to translate the query myself. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to return. First you say that you want to return the indicator. Then you say that you want blank text instead of the indicator. So, if you want blank text, just don't select the indicator.

Comment: I've provided some sample data to illustrate my needs. @JBNizet, I have to select everything, but only show an empty string if there's more than 1 owner_indicator inside a EquipmentGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I thin k you must to use a main query on EquipmentGroup and a subquery about return data on Equipment.
If you have more than 1 equipment rows about one group you must return DISTINCT empty; if you have 1 row returns owner_indicator otherwise you can return 'None'

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eg.name, eg.description, 
(SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN count(e.id) > 1 THEN DISTINCT 'EMPTY'
    WHEN count(e.id) = 1 THEN e.owner_indicator
    ELSE 'none'
END
FROM Equipment e 
WHERE e.equipmentGroup.id = eg.id)
FROM EquipmentGroup eg
```

Comment: shouldn't the count be on eg.id instead of e.id ?

Comment: but what if all the equipments inside the group share the same attributes ? that way I'd like to return it.

Comment: No, because in your example two rows of the same group have 2 owner_indicator